# Suppress console output in python when using ray - SDL warnings

Tags: python, python-3.x, sdl, ray

I am running a **pygame** in parallel using **ray**, but want so suppress SDL video warnings/errors.

Here is my code:

```
@ray.remote
def run2(agent):  # same as run1 

  sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, "w")
  sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, "w") 
  os.environ["SDL_VIDEODRIVER"] = "dummy" 
  env = GameEnv(0)
  state = env.reset()
  steps =0
  done= False
  while not done:
    steps+=1
    action = agent.predict(state)
    ns , r ,done ,i= env.step(env.action_space.sample())
  return steps

# note: maybe run this twice to warmup the system
%time result = ray.get([run2.remote(pops[i]) for i in range(10)])
```

I have tried changing stdout and stderr but that doesn't seem to work, or maybe I should change that somewhere else
Here is the warning's I get for every worker

```
(pid=1128) ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
(pid=1128) ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
(pid=1128) ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
(pid=1128) ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
(pid=1128) ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
(pid=1128) ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
(pid=1128) ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
(pid=1128) ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
```

Is there a way to do this using a ray parameter or global stdout block?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found out you could use:

```
ray.init(log_to_driver=False)
```

To disable ray workers from logging the output.

Comment: I still get warnings messages with this

Comment: @Austin You should not got any messages related to ray itself if you pass `logging_level=logging.FATAL` to `ray.init`, and add `"log_level": "ERROR"` to agent configurations. Yet, you can still have import warnings related to other packages. You need to disable them separatly, for example doing `tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')`  for Tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

`2>/dev/null` worked for me too if you are under UNIX, but it is a little bit radical. Prints will still work inside workers.

So: `python script.py 2>/dev/null`

Answer (score 0):

Edit <python_dir>/Lib/site-packages/ray/_private/ray_constants.py and replace line `LOGGING_LEVEL = "info"` with `LOGGING_LEVEL = "error"`.